# Facebook graph api video: Mobile compatible embed code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Per here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/video

FB Graph API is supposed to give a embed_html for videos. I have a graph object for which I get this. However this doesn't play in mobile safari or embedded webkits. Here is a JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/c12zngwr/

```
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=778091828917868" width="800" height="640"></iframe>
```

Is there a way to get mobile compatible urls from graph id?

Answer (score 0):

the only way right now is to embed the whole post https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts it will be playable in mobile also